# Capsule Exception

Tags: java, bash, java-8, corda

I'm trying to launch the [Corda Tutorial App](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html), and get this error after I '$ sh runnodes'. Haven't worked with JDK before, so seeking granular explanation.

> bash -c 'cd
>   /Users/marieleaf/Dropbox/blockchain/corda/cordapp-tutorial/kotlin-source/build/nodes/Controller;
>   /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 --exec java -Dname=Controller-corda.jar
>   -Dcapsule.jvm.args=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
>   -jar corda.jar && exit'     CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not find Java installation for requested version [Min. Java version: 1.8.0
>   JavaVersion: null Min. update version: {1.8=131}] (JDK required:
>   false). You can override the used Java version with the
>   -Dcapsule.java.home flag. (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)

Comment: do you have java installed?

Comment: Yes. Java 8 Update 131. On Mac 10.12.4

Comment: I uninstalled using Java's directions, reinstalled Java, then rebooted my computer. Works now.

Comment: @mleafer - can you please accept Joel's answer as correct please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have the correct Java version. The required Java version can be found here: https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html#software-requirements (as of Corda 3.1, Corda's minimum supported version of the JVM is version 8u131 of the Oracle JDK 8 JVM).

You can run `java -version` from the terminal to make sure that your installation has been recognised.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that issue starting multiple nodes on a same box with different versions of the same plugin.
Stopping all the old nodes should do the trick.